# Get Spring Boot startup time for Desktop application under 1 second

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx

I have a desktop application written with `Spring Boot 2.7.3` (without the web server) and UI part with `JavaFX`. Everything is working pretty solid. But the startup time of the application is beyond **5s**. And sometimes it takes more than 10s. And this is not because of the hardware as the desktop have decent specs.
*To provide good user experience, I need this startup time below 1s or may be 2s*

**Things I have tried**

- Lazy initialized beans and repositories
- Excluded some autoconfiguration classes to the best of my knownledge

Please suggest me ways to optimize this thing.

Startup Logs

```
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:11,805 [background-preinit] Version:org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:21)]:HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.4.Final
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:11,941 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] SpringApplication:org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting(StartupInfoLogger.java:55)]:Starting application using Java 17.0.2 on Yash-Garg with PID 3728 (started by Yash Garg in C:\Users\Yash\Documents\app)
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:11,943 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] SpringApplication:org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupProfileInfo(SpringApplication.java:640)]:The following 1 profile is active: "default"
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:12,987 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:132)]:Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in LAZY mode.
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:13,185 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:201)]:Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 183 ms. Found 29 JPA repository interfaces.
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,386 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] VersionPrinter:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:Flyway Community Edition 8.5.13 by Redgate
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,386 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] VersionPrinter:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.5.13
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,387 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] VersionPrinter:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,607 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] BaseDatabaseType:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:Database: jdbc:sqlite:C:\Path\To\Database\File (SQLite 3.39)
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,657 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] DbValidate:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:Successfully validated 4 migrations (execution time 00:00.030s)
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,664 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] DbMigrate:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:Current version of schema "main": 1.4
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,664 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] DbMigrate:org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:37)]:Schema "main" is up to date. No migration necessary.
[DEBUG] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,720 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] AutoConfigurationPackages:org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages.get(AutoConfigurationPackages.java:196)]:@EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'in.app'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:14,897 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] Version:org.hibernate.Version.logVersion(Version.java:44)]:HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:15,105 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] Version:org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:56)]:HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:15,193 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] Dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init>(Dialect.java:175)]:HHH000400: Using dialect: org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:15,236 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] Dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init>(Dialect.java:175)]:HHH000400: Using dialect: org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:15,812 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] EhcacheManager:org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:305)]:Cache 'in.app.entity.TaxCodeEntity' created in EhcacheManager.
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:15,826 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] EhcacheManager:org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:305)]:Cache 'in.app.entity.TransactionTypeEntity' created in EhcacheManager.
[INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:16,469 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:437)]:Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT

Positive matches:

```
DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration matched:
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.PooledDataSourceAvailable PooledDataSource found supported DataSource; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceInitializationConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlR2dbcScriptDatabaseInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.JdbcTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.flyway.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - AnyNestedCondition 2 matched 0 did not; NestedCondition on FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayDataSourceCondition.FlywayUrlCondition @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.flyway.url) matched; NestedCondition on FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayDataSourceCondition.DataSourceBeanCondition @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource' (FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayDataSourceCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager', 'org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor' (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapperBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapper matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration#parameterNamesModule matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JtaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.transaction.Transaction' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jta.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   LifecycleAutoConfiguration#defaultLifecycleProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: lifecycleProcessor; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'jdbcTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' (OnClassCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration#persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.dao.exceptiontranslation.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   RestTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' (OnClassCondition)
      - NoneNestedConditions 0 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition.ReactiveWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition)

   RestTemplateAutoConfiguration#restTemplateBuilderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.sql.init.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - NoneNestedConditions 0 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration.SqlInitializationModeCondition.ModeIsNever @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.sql.init.mode=never) did not find property 'mode' (SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration.SqlInitializationModeCondition)

   TemplateEngineConfigurations.DefaultTemplateEngineConfiguration#templateEngine matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.thymeleaf.spring5.ISpringTemplateEngine; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode', 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine' (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: defaultTemplateResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafJava8TimeDialect matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.dialect.Java8TimeDialect' (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafJava8TimeDialect#java8TimeDialect matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.dialect.Java8TimeDialect; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#platformTransactionManagerCustomizers matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnResource found location classpath:META-INF/services/javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider (OnResourceCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration#defaultValidator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.validation.Validator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration#methodValidationPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

Exclusions:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration
```

Unconditional classes:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
```

> [INFO ] [10-09-2022 17:19:16,674 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] SpringApplication:org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted(StartupInfoLogger.java:61)]:Started application in 5.61 seconds (JVM running for 7.131)

Comment: However it may be possible to speed up the startup of your application, in general, I don't think the Spring Boot is being considered fast starting. Probably you should change your approach: either change the framework or rewrite te UI to something else and start Spring service in background or keep some background process from the OS startup moment and just render the UI when user is opening applcation

Comment: @m.antkowicz It's a pretty big application, so neither it is possible to change the framework nor to redesign the UI. But I already tried to start the UI part first and load the spring in background thread but it still takes more than 5s which results in poor experience. Is there any way to reduce this time

Comment: Spring is doing a lot of work at startup, including in your case (from what I can tell) connecting to external databases, etc. You’re not going to be able to control how long that takes from your Java code and/or configuration, since it relies on external resources. The best UX here is probably to display a splash screen while starting Spring in the background, then switching to the real UI when that’s complete. A splash screen should appear easily within one second if you separate everything out correctly.

Comment: @James_D In this case external database is a sqlite database file saved locally on the user's device. And I have seperated the starting UI part to show a Splash Screen within one second but the loading time to show the real UI which uses Spring takes around 5s or more to load, which is slow.

Comment: Is there any suggestion to reduce this time, and I think hikari pool doesn't take more than 20ms, but may be hibernate is taking time.

Comment: I created an empty spring boot hello world application with no dependencies and started it.  On a 2020 MacBook pro, it output `Started HelloBootApplication in 0.58 seconds (JVM running for 0.982)`.  So, even when the app is doing nothing else, it takes a second to start.  Trying to also connect to a database (even a local one) and startup JavaFX, is going to take longer.  So I think your wish of "application under 1 second", is likely unrealistic (at least with today's software and hardware).

Comment: Perhaps [springboot native](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) may improve startup time (I don't know).  I wouldn't expect a five-fold increase in performance for it over startup for a JRE-based runtime though.